# Pandas import error when debugging using PVTS

Tags: python, python-2.7, visual-studio-2012, pandas, ptvs

I am dealing with a very silly error, and wondering if any of you have the same problem. When I try to import pandas using `import pandas as pd` I get an error in copy.py. I debugged into the pamdas imports, and I found that the copy error is thrown when pandas tries to import this: 
 `from pandas.io.html import read_html`

The exception that is throwns is: 
`un(shallow)copyable object of type <type 'Element'>`

I do not get this error if I try to straight up run the code and not use the PVTS debugger. I am using the python 2.7 interpreter, pandas version 0.12 which came with the python xy 2.7.5.1 distro and MS Visual Studio 2012.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you ignore the exception and just continue running, does it terminate? It might be that the exception is always thrown on that code path, it just happens to be handled above, but PTVS is not correctly detecting that.

Comment: Pavel, thanks for the insight. You are correct, if I hit F5 and continue the program keeps running without any issue. What's your suggestion in this case?

Comment: The exception I get is this: `copy.Error occured` So I look for a python exception named `copy` in the exception settings in PTVS and I cannot find it. Interestingly, in the dialog that opens when the exception is thrown, I see that "Break when this exception type is thrown" is unchecked.

Comment: It sounds like it's a custom extension type. We should still be handling this properly, though. There have been some other similar issues reported with exceptions being shown in debugger when they shouldn't (i.e. when they are caught up the stack, and the setting is to not report caught exceptions). Let me try this and see whether I can repro.

Comment: This is now tracked by a bug in PTVS issue tracker: https://pytools.codeplex.com/workitem/2077

Answer (score 5):

This is a limitation of the way PTVS detects unhandled exceptions - it can't see the except-block that's going to catch this exception because it is in the code that is eval'd from a string. See the [bug in the tracker](https://pytools.codeplex.com/workitem/2077) for more details.

As a workaround, disable "Debug standard library" checked in Tools -> Options -> Python Tools -> Debugging - this should cause the exception to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for a while,  disabling "Debug standard library" didn't help, then I downloaded the latest version of Python (3.4), pip installed the libs (for example NLTK), and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I had a system crash while developing a PTVS app and then ran into this problem, re-running the Intellisense 'refresh DB' cleared it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, but just hitting 'Continue' will cause it to be ignored and the code execution will proceed in the usual way.
Or you could uncheck the "Break when this exception type is user-handled" option that comes up in the dialog box displaying the error.