# pandas.io.excel.read_excel throws an exception when run in debug mode but not in python debug interactive

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-2013, pandas

So this is funny. I am using Anaconda install of python 2.7 (64 bit) on a Visual Studio 2013 IDE. I am using pandas version 0.16.1.

I get an error when I try to run the following two lines in the IDE in debug mode:

```
import pandas as pd
RetSeries = pd.io.excel.read_excel('c:/testdata.xlsx','Sheet1')
```

giving:

```
un(shallow)copyable object of type <type 'Element'>" in file cElementTree.py
```

However, the same code works in both Python interactive environment and Python Debug Interactive in Visual Studio.

Furthermore, if I break at line 'RetSeries = ...', execute the line in Python Debug Interactive and then go back to my IDE and continue, the code works.

What could be causing this difference in behavior?

Comment: Is [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20532621/478288) related?

Comment: Thank you. This solves the problem.