# xml.etree error when importing azure.storage.blob

Tags: python, azure

I am using Python 2.7, and have the following statement:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService, ContainerPermissions
```

Usually, this works fine. However, today when I ran the script in Visual Studio, I got the error:

> copy.Error was unhandled by user code Message: un(shallow)copyable
>   object of type

I tried **"pip install azure-storage --upgrade"**, which upgraded everything, but the issue still persists.  See below image.  Any ideas?  thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Will your script run as expected if you ignore this error and click `continue` button to continue the progress?

Comment: Yes it did, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some similar issue with you, [Pandas import error when debugging using PVTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20532621/pandas-import-error-when-debugging-using-pvts) and https://pytools.codeplex.com/workitem/2077.

According the answer of @Pavel Minaev, it seems to be a limitation of the way PTVS detects unhandled exceptions - it can't see the except-block that's going to catch this exception because it is in the code that is eval'd from a string.

You can try to upgrade to the latest version of python and reinstall the packages. Or simply ignore this error, by clicking the `continue` button to continue the python progress.

Comment: Clicking the "continue" button (and ignoring the error) was the solution for me.